# How do I sort a dataGridView the was populated with SqlDataReader and BindingSource , when i push a button

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I am trying to create a sort button , to sort the all ready filtered Data that is in datagridview.

But when i do :

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if (sortComboBox.SelectedItem == "Price low - high")
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Price"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            }
            if (sortComboBox.SelectedItem == "Price high - low")
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Price"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a component");
        }
    }
```

Then it Give me an error:

```
DataGridView control cannot be sorted if it is bound to an IBindingList that does not support sorting.
```

This is how I populated the dataGridView :

```
command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Price],[Mark],[Type],[Code],[Series],[Rating],[Description],[Comments]FROM "+database+" ORDER BY CAST(ID AS INT) ", connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        // Create a BindingSource object
        BindingSource   bs = new BindingSource();

        // Assign the reader to the binding source
         bs.DataSource = reader;
        // Assign the BindingSource to the DataGridView DataSource

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        reader.Close();
```

Please help me to show how sort the Data the user have in the dataGridView currently.

P.S. the allowusertoordercolumns is also not working.

I have this but its not working

```
List<string[]> allDatalist = new List<string[]>();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string[] rowData = new string[8]; // 8 because you're loading from a table with 8 columns
                for (var i = 0; i < rowData.Length; i++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(i));
                    rowData[i] = reader.GetString(i);
                }
                allDatalist.Add(rowData);
            }
            for (var x = 0; x < allDatalist.Count; x++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(allDatalist[x]);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: My personal opinion is, don't use the DataSource property at all. Load the data into a separate list, and sort on that data and then populate your DataGrid with the list data.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard Sorry but i dont completely know to to use lists maby if you can give an example with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

So this is merely pseudo-code, but I'm sure you get the idea:

First load everything into a list:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Price],[Mark],[Type],[Code],[Series],[Rating],[Description],[Comments]FROM "+database+" ORDER BY CAST(ID AS INT) ", connection);
List<object[]> allData = new List<object[]>();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        object[] rowData = new object[8]; // 8 because you're loading from a table with 8 columns
        for (var i = 0; i < rowData.Length; i++)
        {
            rowData[i] = reader.GetObject(i);
        }
        allData.Add(rowData);
    }
}
// Congratulations, you now have a collection containing all the data from your database.
// At this point, you'll want to sort on one of the column (Loop through every row in the allData list, and compare position 0 or 1 or whatever data you want.
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: my reader does not have a .GetObject property : / , shoud i "using" something ?

Comment: In regards to the 'no GetObject' part, you should use the type matching the type in the database. So instead of using a for-loop, do the same line for all 8 objects, and use the respective 'Get' method for each type. So Price would probably be Decimal, Mark is String, Type and Code might be Int's (cause I'm guessing they're normally Enums), etc.

Comment: I am getting some weird results , all my values are strings anyway. Shouldnt object[] rowData = new object[8];  just be string[] s = new string[8]. and how do i load the list into the datagridview ?

Comment: Since all your columns are strings (which I wouldn't recommend, but it's fine), yes you can use string[] instead of object. And to load the list into the datagridview, you'll have to loop through each row in the list of data, and add it as a row in the datagridview. This is a little out-of-date, but it should explain how to work with datagridviews: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Comment: updated my orginal post check my code there ? dont think the GetString is  the one i should use ?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day this was all I wanted..

```
   SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, connectionString); 
             SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
             dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
             dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Now It can be sorted with headers of datagrid.